# Как правильно запустить телеграмм бот на сервере ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот написан на пайтон, использую вебхуки и flask. Размещаю на сервере, ubuntu при помощи файла bot.service. При этом при относительно длительном отсутствии запросов в бот он перезапускается по видимому получая ошибку [Errno 104]. Но это не точно. Не могу понять в чем причина, возможно есть другой способ запуска не через bot.service (но в приоретете все таки bot.service).[image: leg]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Прошу прощения, учту в будущем (не так давно пользуюсь SO)